# Constructor Chaining vs Similar ones

Tags: c#, design

I have the following constructors:

```
public Class1()
{
    this.Variable = new Variable();
}

public Class1(Variable vari)
{
    this.Variable = vari;
}
```

Which can be rewritten as:

```
public Class1()
    : this(new Variable())
{

}

public Class1(Variable vari)
{
    this.Variable = vari;
}
```

Is there any benefit from writing it the second way or would they be practically the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one duplicates logic. Even if said logic consists of a single assignment statement.